# SQLite timestamp conversion

Tags: sqlite, timestamp, unix-timestamp

I have been looking for a solution for certain timestamps I have in a database

I have the following timeStamp: `17914`

how do I convert it to a date in SQLite?

The correct date is 2019-01-18

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this to be a solution:

```
SELECT datetime('1970-01-01','+'||17914||' days')
```